# Oracle: Join 2 tables without an explicit key

Tags: oracle, join

I have 2 table as follows:

| Case_No. | Month | Month_Prev | Code | Stage | Code_Prev | Stage_Prev | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022.09 | 2022.08 | b | 2 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022.09 | 2022.08 | a | 2 | b | 1 | 1 |

and

| Month | Code | Stage | Rate | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022.09 | a | 1 | 0.2 | 1 |
| 2022.09 | a | 2 | 0.1 | 1 |
| 2022.09 | b | 1 | 0.3 | 1 |
| 2022.09 | b | 2 | 0.1 | 1 |
| 2022.08 | a | 1 | 0.3 | 1 |
| 2022.08 | a | 2 | 0.2 | 1 |
| 2022.08 | b | 1 | 0.15 | 1 |
| 2022.08 | b | 2 | 0.25 | 1 |

My desired output:

| Case_No. | Month | Month_Prev | Code | Stage | Code_Prev | Stage_Prev | Status | Rate | Rate_Prev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022.09 | 2022.08 | b | 2 | a | 1 | 1 | 0.1 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 2022.09 | 2022.08 | a | 2 | b | 1 | 1 | 0.1 | 0.15 |

Basically, I want to obtain the rate corresponding to each individual set of {Month, Code, Stage, Status} and {Month_Prev, Code_Prev, Stage_Prev, Status} and I'm using Oracle. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have already shown the keys for the join, so simply apply them. You'll have to join the second table twice, once for Month, once for Month_Prev.

```
select
  t1.*
  this.rate,
  prev.rate as prev_rate
from t1
join t2 this on this.month = t1.month and this.code = t1.code and this.stage = t1.stage and this.status = t1.status
join t2 prev on prev.month = t1.month_prev and prev.code = t1.code and prev.stage = t1.stage and prev.status = t1.status
order by t1.month, t1.code, t1.stage, t1.status;
```

(In case there can be t1 rows without a match in t2 and you still want to show the row without a rate then, then change the inner joins to left outer joins.)